# Where can I find normalized data on governmental spending on science?

Tags: data-request, government

Is possible to get access to data on governmental spending on science in a such format that countries can be compared with each other?

Answer (score 4):

Try the [OECD's Main Science and Technology Indicators](http://stats.oecd.org/Index.aspx?DataSetCode=MSTI_PUB)

Comment: To go with the budget assumption like the others ... see [Other national R-D expenditure by field of science and by source of funds](http://stats.oecd.org/Index.aspx?DataSetCode=ONRD_FUNDS)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you may have a look at Eurostat's data on [Science, technology and innovation](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/science-technology-innovation/data/database).

The geographic coverage is a bit different from the OECD database, but the comparability is better with Eurostat data.

Comment: It looks to me like the data is under 'Research and Development' then 'Government budget appropriations or outlays on R&D '  (as my take on 'spending' is budget info)

Answer (score 1):

There will always remain some discrepancies on how the data is collected and defined.

Good sources, as pointed out before, is [Eurostat](http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/statistics_explained/index.php/R_%26_D_expenditure) with some explanation in the link.

The OECD is a good source and I would also look at indicators published by the [World Bank](http://data.worldbank.org/topic/science-and-technology).

Comment: In following your World Bank link, they have [Research and development expenditure (% of GDP)](http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/GB.XPD.RSDV.GD.ZS).  (although, now that I think about it, not all R&D is science)

Comment: You're prob right – World Bank may not be immediately relevant.